# How to implement zoom and pan using two fingers (both) in this code?

Tags: android, android-canvas, zooming, pinchzoom, touchimageview

This code loads a picture and puts it in a imageView , then you can draw rectangles on the image, using the canvas.
imageView there are two , one for loading an image , the other to draw rectangles on this . I need to zoom and pan (using two fingers for both) in the image and drawing at the same time , can anyone help me ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    Button btnLoadImage;
    TextView textSource;
    ImageView imageResult, imageDrawingPane;

    final int RQS_IMAGE1 = 1;

    Uri source;
    Bitmap bitmapMaster;
    Canvas canvasMaster;
    Bitmap bitmapDrawingPane;
    Canvas canvasDrawingPane;
    projectPt startPt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);

        btnLoadImage = (Button) findViewById (R.id.loadimage);
        textSource = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.sourceuri);
        imageResult = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.result);
        imageDrawingPane = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.drawingpane);

        btnLoadImage.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener ()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick (View arg0)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult (intent, RQS_IMAGE1);
            }
        });

        imageResult.setOnTouchListener (new OnTouchListener ()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event)
            {

                int action = event.getAction ();
                int x = (int) event.getX ();
                int y = (int) event.getY ();
                switch (action)
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        textSource.setText ("ACTION_DOWN- " + x + " : " + y);
                        startPt = projectXY ((ImageView) v, bitmapMaster, x, y);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        textSource.setText ("ACTION_MOVE- " + x + " : " + y);
                        drawOnRectProjectedBitMap ((ImageView) v, bitmapMaster, x, y);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        textSource.setText ("ACTION_UP- " + x + " : " + y);
                        drawOnRectProjectedBitMap ((ImageView) v, bitmapMaster, x, y);
                        finalizeDrawing ();
                        break;
                }
    /*
     * Return 'true' to indicate that the event have been consumed.
     * If auto-generated 'false', your code can detect ACTION_DOWN only,
     * cannot detect ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP.
     */
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    class projectPt
    {
        int x;
        int y;

        projectPt (int tx, int ty)
        {
            x = tx;
            y = ty;
        }
    }

    private projectPt projectXY (ImageView iv, Bitmap bm, int x, int y)
    {
        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > iv.getWidth () || y > iv.getHeight ())
        {
            //outside ImageView
            return null;
        } else
        {
            int projectedX = (int) ((double) x * ((double) bm.getWidth () / (double) iv.getWidth ()));
            int projectedY = (int) ((double) y * ((double) bm.getHeight () / (double) iv.getHeight ()));

            return new projectPt (projectedX, projectedY);
        }
    }

    private void drawOnRectProjectedBitMap (ImageView iv, Bitmap bm, int x, int y)
    {
        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > iv.getWidth () || y > iv.getHeight ())
        {
            //outside ImageView
            return;
        } else
        {
            int projectedX = (int) ((double) x * ((double) bm.getWidth () / (double) iv.getWidth ()));
            int projectedY = (int) ((double) y * ((double) bm.getHeight () / (double) iv.getHeight ()));

            //clear canvasDrawingPane
            canvasDrawingPane.drawColor (Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.CLEAR);

            Paint paint = new Paint ();
            paint.setStyle (Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setColor (Color.WHITE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth (3);
            canvasDrawingPane.drawRect (startPt.x, startPt.y, projectedX, projectedY, paint);
            imageDrawingPane.invalidate ();


            textSource.setText (x + ":" + y + "/" + iv.getWidth () + " : " + iv.getHeight () + "\n" +
                            projectedX + " : " + projectedY + "/" + bm.getWidth () + " : " + bm.getHeight ());
        }
    }

    private void finalizeDrawing ()
    {
        canvasMaster.drawBitmap (bitmapDrawingPane, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Bitmap tempBitmap;

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case RQS_IMAGE1:
                    source = data.getData ();
                    textSource.setText (source.toString ());

                    try
                    {
                        //tempBitmap is Immutable bitmap,
                        //cannot be passed to Canvas constructor
                        tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream (getContentResolver ().openInputStream (source));

                        Config config;
                        if (tempBitmap.getConfig () != null)
                        {
                            config = tempBitmap.getConfig ();
                        } else
                        {
                            config = Config.ARGB_8888;
                        }

                        //bitmapMaster is Mutable bitmap
                        bitmapMaster = Bitmap.createBitmap (tempBitmap.getWidth (), tempBitmap.getHeight (), config);

                        canvasMaster = new Canvas (bitmapMaster);
                        canvasMaster.drawBitmap (tempBitmap, 0, 0, null);

                        imageResult.setImageBitmap (bitmapMaster);

                        //Create bitmap of same size for drawing
                        bitmapDrawingPane = Bitmap.createBitmap (tempBitmap.getWidth (), tempBitmap.getHeight (), config);
                        canvasDrawingPane = new Canvas (bitmapDrawingPane);
                        imageDrawingPane.setImageBitmap (bitmapDrawingPane);


                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace ();
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}




<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loadimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load Image 1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sourceuri"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/drawingpane"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/result"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/result"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/result"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/result"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use TouchImageView https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help.
I started working with android recently as I integrate this with this code?
Again, thank you.